# Scrollview inside ViewPagerFragment from NestedScrollview

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-nestedscrollview

So I have an Activity which uses a NestedScrollView and inside that NestedScrollView is a ViewPager.
That ViewPAger contains 2 fragments. One has layouts inside scrollview and another one has recyclerView.

But both fragments are not scrolling (neither scrollview nor recyclerview).

**Activity XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:orientation="vertical">

               // Some Textview & imagehview here

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll_header"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/movietab"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_2sdp"
                    app:stl_defaultTabTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:stl_defaultTabTextHorizontalPadding="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    app:stl_distributeEvenly="true"
                    app:stl_indicatorColor="@color/white"
                    app:stl_indicatorCornerRadius="1dp"
                    app:stl_indicatorInterpolation="smart"
                    app:stl_indicatorThickness="3dp"
                    app:stl_underlineColor="@color/transparent" />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/mViewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/movietab" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Fragment1 XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color1">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            //Inner Layout


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment2 XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/llCasting"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.movies.MovieCastFragment">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvCast"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I tried `android:nestedScrollingEnabled=""` true and false on each and every layout but never got desired result.

Fragment's ScrollView and RecyclerView are scolling but I don't want to scroll them, I want to scroll Activity's Nested ScrollVIew.

Comment: What happens if you replace `ScrollView` with `NestedScrollView` ? and set `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` before you are setting the adapter

Comment: if I replace `ScrollView` with `NestedScrollView` then only fragament layout is scrolling not activity layout. And If I set `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` then scrolling not working but when I set `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);` then `recyclerView` is scrolling. but same issue, activity layout not scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

The height of your ViewPager should be set to wrap_content and nested scrolling should be set to false so that the parent NestedScrollView will be put in charge of the scrolling.